# Plot inside a loop in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, plot

I am doing something like this:

```
a = [1:100];
for i=1:100,
    plot([1:i], a(1:i));
end
```

My issue is that the plot is not shown until the loop is finished.
How can I show/update the plot in every iteration?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Use [DRAWNOW](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/drawnow.html)

```
a = [1:100];
for i=1:100,
 plot([1:i], a(1:i));
 drawnow
end
```

Alternatively, you may want to have a look at [ANYMATE](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/18210-anymate) from the file exchange.

Comment: While drawnow is the correct answer, I think one can also add a pause(eps) statement in the code in the place of drawnow. When matlab does the pause, even if only for this nano-fraction of a time slice, it also does a refresh on the figure.

Answer (score 6):

Another way to do this if you just want to visualise it without saving the animation, is to use `refreshdata` instead of `plot` for subsequent plots. You will still need to call `drawnow` for it to update on-screen.

either use

```
set(fig_handle,'XData',new_xdata_array)
set(fig_handle,'YData',new_ydata_array)
refreshdata
drawnow
```

or use

```
set(fig_handle,'XDataSource',xdata_array)
set(fig_handle,'YDataSource',ydata_array)

%call this whenever xdata_array and ydata_array are assigned new values to see it updated in the plot
refreshdata
drawnow
```

for your example, this might look like:

```
a=[1:100];

figure;
h=plot(1,a(1));
for i=2:100
  set(h,'XData',[1:i])
  set(h,'YData',a(1:i))
  refreshdata
  drawnow
end
```

It's not all that useful for simple line plots (for which `plot(); drawnow;` is simpler and faster), but when you need to create more complicated figures involving multiple plot types, this can be useful.

Answer (score 3):

From the [documentation for comet.m](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/comet.html)

```
t = 0:.01:2*pi;
x = cos(2*t).*(cos(t).^2);
y = sin(2*t).*(sin(t).^2);
comet(x,y);
```

Answer (score 0):

`Matlab` allows you to sort-of automate a loop statement for variables

```
x = 0.0:0.1:2*pi

plot(x,cos(x));
```

is an example......

A lot of times you don't really need to plot 'in' a loop