# Display images within a loop without user intervention

Tags: matlab

In Matlab, I have a loop that performs operations on arrays.
I would like to display the array at each iteration (using "imagesc" for instance), but without needing user intervention.

I can force Matlab to update the displayed figure by inserting the command "pause" after imagesc, but it needs to be dismissed by a key press.
Without the "pause" command, the figure is not updated before the end of the loop.

Is there a way to update the figure at each iteration of the loop ?

Comment: Duplicate: [MATLAB plot inside a loop](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2800066/52738), [Real time plot in matlab](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3115833/52738), and probably a few others...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using Matlab command [`drawnow`](http://www.mathworks.com.au/help/techdoc/ref/drawnow.html) after the graphing code within the loop.

> `drawnow` causes figure windows and their children to update, and
>   flushes the system event queue. Any callbacks generated by incoming
>   events (e.g., mouse or key events) are dispatched before drawnow
>   returns.

Answer (score 2):

If `drawnow` updates too quickly, you can control the "frame rate" slightly better with `pause(time_in_seconds)`. E.g., to pause for 0.5 seconds use

```
for ...
   % plot stuff
   pause(0.5);
end
```